# Store state for each item separately in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, boolean

`RecyclerView` `OnClick` doesn't work properly. It has to change state to `true` or `false`. When I click on the first item it stores `true` and changes the text. But when I click on other item it changes the state to `false` because the first item set `true`, so the text doesn't change. How to store the states for each item separately?

```
boolean isChange = false;


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final WindowViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Window window = windowList.get(position);

        holder.textViewTitle.setText(window.getTitle());
        holder.textViewChecked.setText(window.getCheck());

        holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(mCtx.getResources().getDrawable(window.getImage()));
////////////////////////////////////////////////
        holder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (!isChange){

                    holder.parentLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#66BB6A"));
                    holder.textViewChecked.setText("True");
                    isChange = true;

                }

                else {

                    holder.parentLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#EEEEEE"));
                    holder.textViewChecked.setText("False");
                    isChange = false;

                }

                //Toast.makeText(mCtx, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
//////////////////////////////////////
    }
```

Comment: This is how RecyclerView works, you will have to store isChange in your Window class, or if it is only for late purpose and should not be store there, create eg. Set or HashMap that will contain id, and current change status, and viewholder will have to ask for this data onBindView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you have a `setCheck()` method for your `Window` object where you store the checked state. The isChange variable you use is not item specific so it keeps the value of the previous checked item.  
From what I understand by your code you should do this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final WindowViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Window window = windowList.get(position);

    holder.textViewTitle.setText(window.getTitle());
    holder.textViewChecked.setText(window.getCheck());

    holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(mCtx.getResources().getDrawable(window.getImage()));

    holder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (window.getCheck().toString.equals("False")) {
                window.setCheck("True");
                holder.parentLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#66BB6A"));
                holder.textViewChecked.setText("True");
            } else {
                window.setCheck("False");
                holder.parentLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#EEEEEE"));
                holder.textViewChecked.setText("False");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use Map?
I see you have some Window model. So you can create a map in you adapter and store a boolean value for each Window key:

```
private Map<Window, Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();
```

And then get value for the current value:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final WindowViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Window window = windowList.get(position);

        holder.textViewTitle.setText(window.getTitle());
        holder.textViewChecked.setText(window.getCheck());

        holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(mCtx.getResources().getDrawable(window.getImage()));
////////////////////////////////////////////////
        holder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                boolean isChange = map.get(window);

                if (!isChange){

                    holder.parentLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#66BB6A"));
                    holder.textViewChecked.setText("True");
                    map.put(window, true);

                }

                else {

                    holder.parentLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#EEEEEE"));
                    holder.textViewChecked.setText("False");
                    map.put(window, false);

                }

                //Toast.makeText(mCtx, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
//////////////////////////////////////
    }
```